# Application is not installed on android devices - Ionic4

Tags: android, cordova, apk, ionic4

I have developed an android application using Ionic4. I am facing an issue when installing the apk in to android devices. **I have seen similar questions but didnt get and proper solution**.
I have used the command

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

This will generate `un-signed-release.apk` but when I try to install it shows **application is not installed**. 
If I run the command `Ionic cordova build android --prod` will generate `debug apk` and can install on devices.

I dont want to sign the apk as I am not uploading to stores. I just want to run it on the devices.
Any help?

### Ionic Info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.12.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.3
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```